# calling cmd line to grab a string value for a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working in a C# Windows form, and I need to pull in the AD site value for a user (for logic in the form).  This means running a cmd process in the form, but it doesn't seem to run the process the same way it does in a console app:

If I add the following cmd.exe calling function in a .NET console app, it works fine:

```
        static string GetSite()
        {
            string siteName = "";
            ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
            start.FileName = @"cmd.exe"; // Specify exe name.
            start.Arguments = @"/c nltest /dsgetsite";
            start.UseShellExecute = false;
            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    siteName = result;
                }
            }

            return siteName;
        }
```

And then in the console app's main method I can just do:

```
            string s = GetSite();
            Console.WriteLine("site is: " + s);
```

If I add the exact same function into partial class MainForm : Form, and then assign it to a string within the public MainForm(), it is unable to populate the string assigned to it:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        string siteName = GetSite(); /* <-- siteName does not get populated */

        GetManagedDrives(siteName);
    }   

    public static string GetSite()  { (*same code above*) } 
}
```

So it is unable to be passed into other functions called in-line in the MainForm().

In a Windows form, does this type of function need to be put somewhere else so it can populate a string in the MainForm() with it?  Thanks!

Comment: Why aren't you using the built-in `.NET` classes to access Active DIrectory properties? E.g. `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry`, `DirectorySearcher`, etc.

Comment: Also, why are you launching a command prompt? Why not simply: `start.FileName = "nltest"; start.Arguments = "/dsgetsite";`

Comment: I may be wrong (I hope I'm wrong) but DirectoryServices does not expose a method to show what AD site the computer is currently affiliated with.  NLTEST happens to report it when you run the command.  I used the cmd.exe method to call it for better troubleshooting outside the app (can other devs run manually from cmd prompt etc).

Comment: Seems like you can pinvoke `DsGetSiteName(string ComputerName, out IntPtr SiteName);` part of the `netapi32.dll`. E.g: http://adcoding.com/using-dsgetsitename-in-c-sample-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-site-where-a-computer-resides/

Comment: It's funny, I found that same site [link](http://adcoding.com/using-dsgetsitename-in-c-sample-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-site-where-a-computer-resides/) as I was waiting on some ideas - it was my first time pinvoking and it worked perfectly.  If you mark it as an answer I'll confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pinvoke to get the site name, e.g:

```
[DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int DsGetSiteName(String ComputerName, out IntPtr SiteName);

[DllImport("netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern int NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr dwBuffer);

public static String GetSiteName(String computerName = "") {
    IntPtr ptr;
    String siteName;
    int NO_ERROR = 0;

    int ret = DsGetSiteName(computerName, out ptr);
    if (ret == NO_ERROR) {
        siteName = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptr);
        NetApiBufferFree(ptr);
    }
    else
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);

    return siteName;
}
```

sources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dsgetdc/nf-dsgetdc-dsgetsitenamea

http://adcoding.com/using-dsgetsitename-in-c-sample-how-to-get-the-name-of-the-site-where-a-computer-resides/

Comment: Note to moderator: I'm not sure I can edit the subject of the post myself, but it should be changed to something like: "Determine AD site for Windows Form" as we did not end up calling a cmd process in the Form as originally planned.